# How to show notification in center of the page (jsom, SpOnline2013)?

Tags: notifications

I have big EditForm with many fields, users scroll it down. Near "Save" button I placed my custom button with some js. I show notifications programmatically (SP.UI.Notify.addNotification, addStatus) but they appear at the top and are not visible to users.

Can I put SharePoint notification in another place?

**upd.:** Forms are opened "in dialog"

Comment: Is a limitation in the MS approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But you can style it

(from F12 console) Put a Notification on screen to play with it:

```
 SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Hello World',true);
```

Change CSS with higher CSS Specificity,
to fixed it in the top right

```
.ms-notif-box.ms-notif-box {
   position: fixed;
   top: 15em;
   right: 2em
}
```